# Can I use cppcheck when I execute :wq in Vim editor for c/c++

Tags: vim, cppcheck

I want to override wq/q/w!/w/q! to user defined command along with its functionality.

Example :

If I use :wq to exit, the command should do static code check of that particular c/c++ file and exit.

Please help me in this case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

The built in solution to your problem is called an "autocommand" in Vim.

It is a way to invoke a command at a specific time like opening, saving or closing a buffer.

See `:help autocmd` for the full list

In your case, you should add to your `.vimrc` the following command

`autocmd BufWritePre *.cpp,*.hpp !cppcheck %`

- `BufWritePre` means 'before writing the buffer' (You can also use `BufWrite` or `BufWritePost`)
- `*.cpp,*.hpp` means the auto command will only be applied when saving cpp or hpp files. You can add c and h files if you want.
- `%` means 'path of the current buffer'
- `cppcheck` must be in your path

You are not overriding the defaut behaviour of 'w' but you are using 'hooks' to add custom commands.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't do that. It obliges us (well, you actually) to save only when the file is really compilable -- which make no sense when we have to abort the current editing because an urging meeting that we've forget about is about to begin; saving the file in that situation is the normal way to proceed.

Moreover, what is the purpose of running cppcheck on a `:wq`? How can we exploit the result?

Instead, I'd have a mapping that run cppcheck, though :make in order to exploit the vim quickfix feature (:h quickfix)

```
function s:Check()
  try
    let save_makeprg=&makeprg
    set makeprg=cppcheck
    " you may have to specify other files/extensions
    :make *.cpp *.hpp
  finally
    let &makeprg=save_makeprg
  endtry
endfunction
nnoremap <buffer> <c-f7> :call <sid>Check()<cr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<block>
function FunForQuickfix(makeprgIn, makeefmIn)
  try
    let save_makeprg=&makeprg
    let save_makeefm=&efm
    let &makeprg=a:makeprgIn
    let &efm=a:makeefmIn
    :wa
    :make
    :cw
  finally
    let &makeprg=save_makeprg
    let &efm=save_makeefm
  endtry
endfunction

function CompileAndRunTestCodeByScons()
  call FunForQuickfix('scons . -j8 -u', '%f:%l:%c:\ %m,%f:%l:\ %m,build/release64/%f:%l:%c:\ %m,build/release64/%f:%l:\ %m,%f\|%l\|,build/release64/%f:%s,%m:%l:Assertion,%sExpression:\ false,scons:\ building\ terminated\ because\ of\ errors,%sError%m')
endfunction
function CppCheck()
  call FunForQuickfix("cppcheck *.cpp -j 8 --enable=all", "\[%f:%l\]:\ %m")
endfunction
nmap ma :wa<CR>:call CompileAndRunTestCodeByScons()<CR>
nmap mc :wa<CR>:call CppCheck()<CR>
nmap <F3> :cp<cr>
nmap <F4> :cn<cr>

</block>
```

add this in ~/.vimrc, then use ma to compile code and mc to run cppcheck
this code is copy from Luc Hermitte, and i chang it

Answer (score 0):

You might want some things even better, use cppcheck and other checkes while you are developing in vim.

Install and use that vim plugin: https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic